# How do multiple recursive calls work in Python

Tags: python, recursion

Below is a recursion function to decode a string. Can somebody explain to me **step by step** how multiple recursive calls work? Does the func finish the first recursive call and move on to the next recursive call? or does it do a recursive call within a recursive call?

```
def encodings(str, prefix = ''):
    encs = []
    if len(str) > 0:
        es = encodings(str[1:], (prefix + ',' if prefix else '') + str[0])
        encs.extend(es)
        if len(str) > 1 and int(str[0:2]) <= 26:
            es = encodings(str[2:], (prefix + ',' if prefix else '') + str[0:2])
            encs.extend(es)
    return encs if len(str) else [prefix]
```

```
print(encodings("1234"))
```

This is what you get. Why?

```
['1,2,3,4', '1,23,4', '12,3,4']
```

Comment: Side note: try not to use a data type as the argument or any variable name.

Comment: Recursion works pretty much the same in any language.  I might recommend trying a simpler example if you're trying to understand recursion for the first time -- factorial and fibonacci functions are classic examples that you can implement recursively in only a couple lines of code and very easily understand what each recursive call is doing.  With this `encodings` function it's not obvious to me (and probably not obvious to you either) what it's supposed to be doing even at a high level, which is going to make it hard to reason about its individual substeps.

Comment: To make @xihtyM 's comment more explicit: do not use `str` as the name of a variable. `str` is already the name of the whole class for strings, and shadowing that name by using it for something else is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes you are right, i should've used another var as parameter, not str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to 'visualize' what your snippet does, you can use :
https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

You'll see step by step why you have `['1,2,3,4', '1,23,4', '12,3,4']` as outpout